#  two background images in IE

Tags: html, css

how can i use 2 image for the body the first background will be at the top with no repeat , the second image will be after the first one with repeat , in Firefox i can do that easily but my problem in IE 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you provide some code to clarify what's the problem. The problem might not be in the code for the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to add [multiple backgrounds in IE](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Cross_Browser_Multi_background_images__including_I-16839.html) using a proprietary filter

As taken from the linked site, the IE code is as follows:

```
<!--[if gt IE 7]> 
<style type="text/css"> 
/* The proprietary zoom property gives IE the hasLayout property which addresses several bugs, dont forget to insert your wrappers id */ 
#outerWrapper #contentWrapper, #outerWrapper #contentWrapper #content { 
  zoom: 1; 
} 
/* Now lets make it IE8 Multi-background images */ 
#multipleBackgroundImages { 
  background-image: url(../images/lilys.jpg); 
  background-position: bottom right; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../images/lakeside2.png', sizingMethod='crop')"; 
  border: 1px solid black; 
  padding: 0 1em; 
} 
/* Fix for IE clearType */ 
#multipleBackgroundImages p { 
    position: relative; /* required to re-enable IE's clearType */ 
   } 
</style> 
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 2):

Attach one to `html` and another to `body` -

```
html{
  background: url() repeat-y left top;
}
body{
  background: url() no-repeat left top;
}
```

Comment: +1 This is a quite common and solid solution. This is what i would do… There is no need for additional markup or a proprietary filter.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code. This supports all browsers including IE

```
body{
    width:800px; height:750px;
    background: url(http://www.google.com/logos/2012/indonesiaind12-hp.jpg), url(http://www.google.com/logos/2012/india12-hp.jpg);
    background-position:top, bottom;
    background-repeat:no-repeat, no-repeat   
   }​
```

You can get the detailed explanation [here](http://userinterfacehome.blogspot.in/2012/09/css-multiple-background.html)

Answer (score 0):

use nested div's and apply one background for one and another for another

```
<div class="background-bottom"><div class="background-top"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its Simple you have to split the body into two seperate div's in that you can do that easily. top div and bottom div must have those two images as their background.

It may work in IE